# How to build an installer to update an ASP.NET's web.config, DLL, files, etc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, installation, windows-installer

I have an add-on for a commercial ASP.NET website. My add-on requires people to merge entries into their web.config, add/overwrite existing files, and add some DLL files to the bin folder.

Is there a good and safe way to create an installer than can do this with a wizard type of installation? It would really help non-technical people install the add-on easily. Maybe even a web-based installer would be good?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar problem...

### Web.Config

- Created a .NET command line program that you can call from your installer passing it the web.config path and other args to match what I'm trying to do
- In the command line program you can then modify the web.config to your needs...  Below is an example of setting a connection string & the stmp from address in a web.config

  ```
  public static void SetConnectionString(string name, string connString, string webConfigPath)
  {
      string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(webConfigPath);
      VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(directory, true);
      WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
      wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
      System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
      webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString = connString;
      webConfig.Save();
  }


  public static void SetFromAddress(string email, string webConfigPath)
  {
      string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(webConfigPath);
      VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(directory, true);
      WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
      wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
      System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/"); 
      System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = (System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup)webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
      mailSettings.Smtp.From = email;
      webConfig.Save();
  }
  ```

### Installer

I used NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).  Use **HM NIS Edit** as a good starting point as it has a wizard that will generate scripts for you.  From there you can modify up the scripts to your needs.  In my case I called my command line program after the files where installed.  Example NSIS script below.

```
Section "My Config Wizard" SecWizard
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\Bin\My.Config.Wizard.exe" "$INSTDIR"'
Return
SectionEnd
```

Good luck!  Need more examples just hit me up. :P

Comment: Ok but how do you know, in advance, the web config path ? In my ASP.NET msi installation, the user will select a web application where to install the ASP.NET application, therefore I don't know where the web.config file is

Answer (score 0):

The web.config is the tricky part.  Your first installer will deploy an XML file and then a user will change something in it.  Meanwhile you  have another build where the developer makes changes to the XML and now the installer has to try to figure out how that should merge all back together.

Out of the box, it can't.

2 strategies that I've used over the years:

1) Have the installer smart enough to pick out key pieces of information from the xml before replacing the xml.  Then apply the information back.

2) Design your software to have 2 XML files.  One that the installer can safely always overwrite and the other to act as an override that the user can modify safely.